# How to make this API: /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information to return email field

Tags: magento2, shipping

My question is simple:

I wish to fetch the shipping email field by calling:
/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information

Is it possible by changing some codes?

I searched through the whole StackExchange / Google for any possible clue / source code. Tested mostly I could but all of them renders no response. Is it that hard to just add a single new column / field into the database for use? Can Magento 2 recognize a certain new column & load the data into the model objects if I just simply insert the column with MySQL Softwares like Sequel Pro?

I wrote:

```
namespace SR\CheckoutAdditionalField\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();

        $column = [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment' => 'Shipping Email',
            'default' => '0'
        ];
        $connection->addColumn($setup->getTable('sales_order'), 'shipping_email', $column);
    }
}
```

But nothing happened. Nothing new has been added into "sales_order" table.